# $http.get request fails when I toggle the device mode in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, http, request

I'm running an API in an `apache` local virtual host and my client in another one.

My AngularJS application is working great in `Chrome` when device mode is toggled off but it throws me an error when it's toggled on:

```
angular.min.js:93 GET https://api.server.com 403 (Forbidden)
```

Here bellow I paste the code:

```
var storyFactory = angular.module('story.services', []);

storyFactory.factory('storyVideos', function ($http) {

    var factory = {
        story: {}
    };

    factory.getJSON = function (url, story_id) {
        return $http.get(url + '/5727cce5cf3ad/story/get/' + story_id).then(function (response) {
            return angular.extend(factory.story, response.data);
        });
    };

    return factory;
});
```

I've discarded a problem on my server side since I don't get back any error and it acceps `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I've also test adding a `manifest.json` to my `index.html` as it follows:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "https://api.server.com/*"
    ]
}
```

Does anybody have any clue about what's happening?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Sure does look like it's on your server--The 403 error means the server did return with a Forbidden, 403 code. When you turn on device mode on your browser, it changes your user-agent... do you have any user-agent or referrer checking on your server?

Comment: @rgthree I don't have any user-agent condition check on the server.

Comment: @rgthree found the mistake. As you suggested, it was on my server!

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error means the server returned `Forbidden` code.

This is most likely a server side issue.